# CreateDirectory windows API issue

Tags: c++, windows

i am using CreateDirectory given path which holds "d:\temp\s1\"
the function fails once in a 1000 times as my probability of hitting same no is less which i think it's not an issue , but if returns "ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS" it still creates that directory

e.g. i have this dir structure

```
d:\temp\s1\1002
d:\temp\s1\1009
..............
..............
```

so on say 30 such folders,
when getLastError() returns "ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS" i continue the loop
and checks for next random no.
what i found is those new directories are getting created infinitely which are not previously exists... that is very strange any help would be best as it's very random nature

code is like that...

```
int randNo = 0;
while(1)
    {
    randNo = rand(); 
    cnt++;
    sprintf(tempDirPath,"d:\\temp\\S1\\%d",randNo);

    mbstowcs(wBuf,tempDirPath,_MAX_PATH);
    bVal = CreateDirectory((LPCTSTR)wBuf,NULL);
    retVal = GetLastError();

    if( retVal == ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS)
    {
        continue;                   
    }
    else if (retVal == ERROR_PATH_NOT_FOUND)
    {
        bVal = CreateFolder(tempDirPath); // i'm creating a folder for further use
    }
    break;      
}
```

Comment: So you get two directories with the same name?

Comment: On what basis are you determining your low probability of a repeat number for your pseudo-random directory names?

Comment: no but if returns "ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS" then it should not create it right !!! @Joachim

Comment: Well, you get that error when a directory by that name already exist, so you of course _have_ that directory already, it's not created again.

Comment: @Prasad: You're mistaken. If it returns `ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS`, then someone has created the directory earlier. And obviously the directory must still exist after `CreateDirectory` returns `ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS`, it's not like `CreateDirectory` would **remove** a directory that already existed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I can guess what your problem is: You check the error codes from `GetLastError` even when there is no error. Always check the value returned by `CreateDirectory` before checking the error code.

What happens here is that `CreateDirectory` fails, setting the error code. Then next time you call `CreateDirectory` it succeeds but it doesn't clear the error code, leaving it as it was the last time the function failed.

It's not only for `CreateDirectory`, *all* functions that can fail will return a value indicating it failed, only then can you check `GetLastError` to get what the error is.

Comment: ok that's cool but you said 'not clear previous error' is it causing any problem!!! or how to clear it then

Comment: @Prasad You don't need to. Check `bVal` before checking what `GetLastError` returns.

Comment: @Prasad you can use [SetLastError](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680627(v=vs.85).aspx) if you want. No, it's not a "problem". He meant clear the previous error *message*. There is no dangerous error here.

Comment: hmm i tried this thing.... if(bVal != 0)
  {
   CreateFolder(tempDirPath);
  }
  else
  {

   retVal = GetLastError();
  
   if( retVal == ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS)
   {
    continue;     
   }
   else if (retVal == ERROR_PATH_NOT_FOUND)
   {
    bVal = CreateFolder(tempDirPath);
   }
  }.............

Comment: is it fine @JoachimPileborg